# How to download a page with lazy loading?

Tags: python, web-scraping, urllib

I need to download full page and parse it, but it creates some elements with help JavaScript. When i try to do this with help **urllib** i receive an html page without elements using JavaScript. How can I solve this problem?

```py
import urllib.request as urlib

page = urlib.urlopen('https://www.example.com')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html5lib')
...
```

Trying:

```
colordiv = soup.select("div.pswp__item:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > img:nth-child(1)'")[0]
```

With:

```
https://www.electrictobacconist.com/smok-nord-p5831
```

Comment: can you include the url and explain exactly what you are after?

Comment: [link](https://www.electrictobacconist.com/smok-nord-p5831)  select colors `colordiv = soup.select("div.pswp__item:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > img:nth-child(1)'")[0]`

Comment: Use Selenium...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the page is rendered using JavaScript, the data is received via an ajax response in the background. All you have to do is make that request.

```
import requests
import re
url='https://www.electrictobacconist.com/smok-nord-p5831'
#get 5831
product_id=re.findall(r'\d+', url)[-1]
r=requests.get("https://www.electrictobacconist.com/ajax/get_product_options/{}".format(product_id))
print([x['value'] for x in r.json()['attributes'][0]['values']])
```

Output:

```
['Black/Blue', 'Black/White', 'Bottle Green', 'Full Black', 'Prism Gold', 'Prism Rainbow', 'Red', 'Resin Rainbow', 'Yellow/Purple', 'Blue/Brown', 'Red/Yellow', 'Red/Green', 'Black/White Resin']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dev tools to find the request used to updated the values for colours

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.electrictobacconist.com/ajax/get_product_options/5831').json()
colours = [item['value'] for item in r['attributes'][0]['values']]
print(colours)
```

---

[image]